# solution of the integral equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

let $y(x)$ be the solution of the integral equation

$$ y(x) = x-\int _0 ^x xt^2y(t)dt, x>0$$

Then value of $y(\sqrt 2)?$

Comment: Hint:
$$(\frac{y}{x})^{\prime}=-x^2y(x)$$

Comment: i also have some problem when i use derivative under integral sign

Answer (score 4):

We have that
$$\frac{y(x)}{x} = 1-\int _0 ^x t^2y(t)dt$$
and after  taking the derivative we obtain
$$y'(x)x-y(x)=-x^4y(x)$$
that is, for $y(x)\not=0$,
$$\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}=\frac{1}{x} -x^3$$
By solving the separable differential equation we get
$$y(x)=Cxe^{-x^4/4}\quad \text{with $C\in \mathbb{R}$.}$$
Now go back to the integral equation, find the constant $C$ and determine the value of $y(\sqrt 2)$.

Comment: This is nice manipulation. So we cannot proceed if we directly differentiate?

Comment: @samjoe In order to eliminate the integral it is better to move $x$ to the other side.

Comment: That I can very well see! But proceeding directly by integration produces linear equation $y' = 1-x^3 y$, solving which becomes impossible. My question was that how can  we proceed using that approach, if possible. :)

Comment: By directly differentiating, is there something wrong?

Comment: @samjoe  The derivative $\int _0 ^x xt^2y(t)dt$ is $\int _0 ^x t^2y(t)dt+x^3y(x)$

Comment: Looks like i have forgotten how to differentiate. Thank you robert z!